# Ask for help to prove a inequality, thanks

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, space-complexity

Can anyone help to prove that
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) > cn$ for some constant $c>0$?
Here $k=\Big[\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\Big]$ and $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$, for example, x=5.2999, then $[x]=5$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you encounter this sum?

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is equal to $\log_2 \binom{n}{k-1}$.

Let $\ell = k-1$. It is well-known that $(n/\ell)^\ell \leq \binom{n}{\ell} \leq (en/\ell)^\ell$, and so your sum is $\ell (\log(n/\ell) + O(1))$.

Now $\ell = \Theta(n/\log n)$ and $\log(n/\ell) = \log \Theta(\log n) = \Theta(\log\log n)$, so altogether your sum is $\Theta(n\log\log n/\log n)$.